# Is there a way for the host of a Zoom meeting running the Zoom app on a Mac to admit everyone from the waiting room via keyboard not mouse?

Tags: macos, applescript, zoom.app

If I am the host of a Zoom meeting and people arrive at the meeting late and I want to admit them to the meeting without interrupting the flow of my presentation, is there any way to "Admit all from Waiting Room" from the keyboard? This is further complicated by the fact that if only one person is in the waiting room, there is no "Admit all" option.

Things I've unsuccessfully tried:

- There is no [pre-defined keyboard shortcut](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205683899-Hot-Keys-and-Keyboard-for-Zoom) for admitting people from the waiting room
- There is no menu item in Zoom to admit from waiting room, so I can't assign a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences
- The "Admit all" button doesn't appear in the same place on the screen depending on how many people are in the waiting room, so it looks like simulating a mouse click at particular coordinates wouldn't work.

I don't know if there is a path forward with UI Scripting through AppleScript, or if I'm overlooking a simulated mouse click solution, or if there's something else I'm not thinking of, but I'd love to be able to admit latecomers to a zoom meeting from the keyboard.

Comment: Perhaps another approach would ease the situation. Delegate a trusted member (or members) in the Zoom meeting as a [co-host or cohosts](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/206330935-Enabling-and-adding-a-co-host), and they will take over admittance and other administrative duties for you while you concentrate on the meeting itself. We've used this option in large-scale faculty meetings (>150) and grade- and school-wide meetings (> 400) for the past year or so at my school. This is also a perfect solution for guest speakers who are then absolved of having to run the meeting themselves.

Comment: Have you tried using **Accessibility Inspector**, a part of **Xcode**, to see what the **UI element** _hierarchical structure_ of the **Admit all from Waiting Room** _button_ is and if **System Events** can _click_ it or use an **AXPress** _action_? Or use **Automator** to record the process and then convert the **Watch Me Do** _action_ to **AppleScript** _code_? Or use [**UI Browser**](https://pfiddlesoft.com/uibrowser/) to ascertain the **UI element** _hierarchical structure_? When there is only one person waiting how do let them in the room? Is there any button or what for that?

Comment: As far as the **Admit all from Waiting Room** _button_ changing position on the screen, that shouldn't be a problem if that **UI element** exposes it properties, i.e., _position_ and _size_ to determine where to click it with, e.g., [**cliclick**](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick), but better if the **UI element** _hierarchical structure_ and **AXPress** _action_ are exposed so **System Events** and interact with it.

Comment: @IconDaemon I love that idea for when it works, but there are contexts where I am unable or not allowed to set a co-host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of scenarios to consider.

1. Showing/hiding the Participants view
2. No people in the waiting room
3. Only one person waiting in the waiting room
4. More than one person waiting.

I'll cover only the case where the Participants View is already active, and the Admit All link is visible due to multiple clients on the waiting list.

This code will click the "Admit All" link

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "zoom.us"
    click last UI element of UI element 1 of row 1 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window "Zoom Meeting"
end tell
```

To Bind it to a keyboard, 2 options:

1. Use Keyboard Maestro to run an AppleScript on a hotkey trigger - Simplest, but KM is not free.
2. I'll save the script above as an Application so that it's available to run from the Spotlight.

Comment: You don't need keyboard maestro or spotlight. Just create a service via Automator and then create a keyboard shortcut for it in system preferences.

Comment: I guess now it's called a "quick action", not service.